# dynamic add input in ng-repeat causes last element to steal focus in safari

Tags: angularjs, safari, mobile-safari

I'd like users to be able to enter multiple answers to a question, so I have an ng-repeat of text inputs that grows as the user adds more answers.

This is working fine in chrome, but in safari, the last element steals the focus as soon as it's added spreading a fast typing user's answer across several inputs.

In iOS safari it's even worse, as it's causing the browser to hang.

Here's the code for the form

```
<form class="form-horizontal sparse" 
        ng-controller="AssessmentController as assessment">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group alt-uses-list" ng-repeat="response in answer.responses">
            <label for="answer{{$index}}" class="col-xs-1 control-label">{{$index + 1}}.</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                    id="response.uses{{$index}}"
                    autocomplete="off" tabIndex="{{$index + 1}}" 
                    autofocus="{{$first}}" ng-model="response.value"
                    ng-change="assessment.addAnswerIfNeeded()">
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here's the controller

```
function AssessmentController($scope, $log) {
    $scope.answer = {};
    $scope.answer.responses = [{id:0, value:""},{id:1, value:""}];

    this.addAnswerIfNeeded = addAnswerIfNeeded;

    // Add answer if the last two answers are non-empty
    function addAnswerIfNeeded() {
      var answers = $scope.answer.responses;

      if ((answers[answers.length - 1].value != '') || 
          (answers[answers.length - 2].value != '')) {
        addAnswer();
      }
    }

    // Adds a new answer if this is the last element
    // isLast is needed to prevent non-lazy evaluation bugs
    function addAnswer() {
        $scope.answer.responses.push({
             id:$scope.answer.responses.length, value: ""
        });
    };
}
```

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfahr5z2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `autofocus` attribute is a `Boolean` type.

According to [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean):

> The value passed as the first parameter is converted to a boolean value, if necessary. If value is omitted or is 0, -0, null, false, NaN, undefined, or the empty string (""), the object has an initial value of false. All other values, including any object or the string "false", create an object with an initial value of true.
>
> Do not confuse the primitive Boolean values true and false with the true and false values of the Boolean object

`autofocus="{{$first}}"` generates `autofocus="false"` on any item that is not the first item in the `ng-repeat`. As the link states

> All other values, including any object or the string **"false"**, create an object with an initial value of **true**.

If you can update to a angular JS version that includes the `ng-attr` directive you can update your code to be the following, I have updated you [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2hzx7rk/5/) to show a working example

```
<form class="form-horizontal sparse" ng-controller="AssessmentController as assessment">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group alt-uses-list" ng-repeat="response in answer.responses">
      <label for="answer{{$index}}" class="col-xs-1 control-label">{{$index + 1}}.</label>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="response.uses{{$index}}" autocomplete="off" tabIndex="{{$index + 1}}" ng-attr-autofocus="{{$first||undefined}}" ng-model="response.value" ng-change="assessment.addAnswerIfNeeded()">
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

When the `ng-attr-autofocus="{{$first||undefined}}"` evaluates to false, the `autofocus` attribute gets the value of `undefined` and thus the `autofocus` gets removed from the dom.

Comment: That did it. Thanks for the help.